# Современный молодёжный сленг: понять и простить? Или?

Tags: жаргон, филозабавы

Хотел обсудить вот такой вопрос.

Все мы наверняка сталкивались с молодёжным сленгом и его проявлениями. Я говорю о таких словах, как "Кринж", "Байтить", "Краш".

Считаете ли Вы это закономерным развитием нашего Русского Языка, или же это чужеродная примесь, в результате которой получился "мертворождённый ребёнок", "бесперспективный сплав" или даже "раковая опухоль" на теле Языка?

В некотором смысле, современный Русский язык - это тоже трансформация чего-то, что существовало до него.

Поэтому вопрос не такой простой, как кажется на первый взгляд.

Что касается молодёжного сленга, то эти изменения лично я воспринимаю, как крайне катастрофические, и "по достоинству оценить" пока не могу, а может быть и никогда не смогу.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, с какой катастрофической примеси вы начали писать "русский" с заглавной буквы? А "Язык" - это что, погоняло онкологического польного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас же не смущают слова "сленг", "бесперспективный", "трансформация", "катастрофические"?

Если в языке нет слова, которое бы четко, кратко, и ёмко описало бы конкретный концепт в голове говорящего, но таковое есть в другом известном ему языке (например "cringe"), то почему бы и не заимствовать термин?

Если приживется и будет удобен, то войдет со временем в язык. Если нет, то пропадет.

Кстати, я заметил, что вы использовали следующую формулировку: "нашего Русского Языка".

Если под *нашим* вы имеете в виду тот вариант русского языка, который используем конкретно мы с вами, то не допускать попадания в него новых терминов—это вполне в ваших силах.

Если же вы подразумеваете, что, как носители языка, мы имеет какое-либо право собственности над всем русским языком, то тут не могу согласиться.

Язык не наш. Он ничей. И попытки сделать его пользование эксклюзивным никогда не работают, даже в контексте таких специфических понятий как торговая марка (глаголы "гуглить" и "ксерокопировать" тому прямое подтверждение).